# Cannot initialise Parse in javascript

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

I have a self hosted parse-server. However I can't seem to do a simple object save in javascript.

My server runs fine and am able to do the parse-server-example.

However, when I try to add a new page it doesn't appear to work.

In my Index.js I have the line

```
app.get('/testsave', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/simplesave.html'));
});
```

then in /public/simplesave.html:

```
<script src="/public/assets/js/simplesave.js"></script>
```

and finally in /public/assets/js/simplesave.js:

```
$(function() {

    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    testObject.save({foo: "bar"}).then(function(object) {
      alert("yay! it worked");
    });

});
```

Replace this with a xhttp.send() however works.
I think I am correct in assuming that Parse does not need to be initialised again and I can simple call Parse.

going to localhost:1337/testsave I would expect the function to be called and a TestObject. However I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line to simplesave.html worked:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
```